# Moderators Pro Tempore, on a sturdy tray covered by plastic bowls

Tags: discussion, moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Susan]
[image: anongoodnurse]
[image: michaelpri]
[image: JohnP]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.** Until that time, we're very lucky to have upstanding members of the community willing to volunteer their time for this.

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: I like the choice, but didn't @Anongoodnurse decline?

Comment: Congratulations to the new moderators.

Comment: @sterno she has to accept the mod agreement. If she doesn't want to do it, that will count as a decline.

Comment: Ditto @JohnP. The site is in good hands.

Comment: @Sterno -  After a conversation with Shog9 in which we discussed my hesitation, I accepted the offer that was extended. I will do my utmost to serve the community well (about that I have no hesitation!)

Comment: Yihiii! <insert some crowd, flowers, music, people raising appreciation posts here>

Comment: @anongoodnurse Excellent

Comment: @JohnP You got it!!! It'll be nice to work with you :)

Comment: Congratulations.. :) happy to see the best people among all as moderators.. :) all the best for you all.. :)

Answer (score 15):

Congratulations to the new <strike>lords</strike> Mods.

[image: Congratulations]

Comment: Thanks, @Ankit Sharma! That is incredibly cute and kind. Also *cookies!!!*