# Should my answers get removed, because of my personal style?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers

As [Shog9](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/251/114) and [JohnP](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/254/114) suggested, my writing:

> appear to share the same characteristics

such as:

> - Start with a general-purpose explanation of the question's topic, paraphrased from another site.
> - Follow with a list of references and excerpts that may be useful in answering the question.
> - The most distinctive aspect of these appears to be that, unlike most other answerers
> - obscure your answer within tangential commentary
> - I'm not sure if this is a personal style, if it is a side-effect of how you research these questions, or a side-effect of the nature of the questions you're answering

and many more.

List of removed answers include (and this is not full list and not only mine are removed):

- [What is the current reason of answer removal: 'symptoms and how migraine is categorised'?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253/what-is-the-current-reason-of-answer-removal-symptoms-and-how-migraine-is-cate)
- [Glaucoma answer removed because of a shotgun approach?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249/glaucoma-answer-removed-because-of-a-shotgun-approach)
- [Should mod remove answers which doesn't address all sub-questions?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/should-mod-remove-answers-which-doesnt-address-all-sub-questions)
- [What's wrong with my answer to cold in summers with nose bleeding issues?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243/whats-wrong-with-my-answer-to-cold-in-summers-with-nose-bleeding-issues)
- [Confusing CPR question](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/confusing-cpr-question)

First of all, I'm not native speaker, secondly I don't believe removing answer because of my personal style is enough reason. This is against the rules described in [Help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Since new [pro tempore mod](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/223/114) were selected, answers are get removed massively for any slight excuses and it is hidden under the carpet.

The process of removal share the same characteristics as well:

1. First the answers are removed for fair point, like lack of references or too many/long cites.
2. Then when answer gets corrected, it gets rejected for undeletion because it's interpreted in this way that it doesn't answer exact questions of OP.
3. After the answers are corrected, another excuse is that it doesn't address everything.
4. After the answers are corrected (which probably wasn't expected to get so far), it's kept in removed state, because of my 'personal style' or 'general-purpose explanation'?

Really? It sounds like a loop-hole. Removing for fair reason, but keeping it deleted for not fair reason.

And sometimes answers are get removed for no reason (without any comment). I understand that down-votes can be anonymous, but removal should be clarified, as I can't improve something that I'm not aware of.

Shouldn't the answer be undeleted once the initial problem has been sorted out? By not finding another extra reasons for keeping it deleted (which weren't addressed at the first place when it was removed)?

What happened to SE community rule where votes and community suggestions in comments are the main indication that my answer should be improved (which I'm doing every time). I believe the Community should decide whether the answer should be published on the site or not.

As far as I can see, the [reasons for deletion](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) can be:

> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

If there are missing reasons, like personal style, please add it there to avoid further confusion.

If you want a better way of saying that my answers are not welcomed here, just say it and I won't participate on the site anymore. Simple as that.

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote the question. Is there something wrong with what @kenorb is asking?

Comment: @DaveL http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291438/are-meta-downvotes-discouraging-users-from-improving-their-questions

Comment: @DaveL I think by down-voting, people actually agree that mods should remove the answers for its personal style further discouraging the users. I think I've found another loophole on the site, seems that people instead of contacting author via votes and comment to suggest improvements, they flag the posts for moderation and it can be removed for some non-related reasons (and I think they're doing this deliberately).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should read [this meta announcement](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/the-road-to-public-beta-time-to-clean-up-qa-on-health-stack-exchange). I'm not familiar with Health.SE, but even I could easily find that this site *does* have a nascent policy to have a high quality requirement on answers, and delete answers that do not meet these requirements:

> - Flag answers that do not attempt to answer the question. Interesting tangents may be interesting, but an answer needs to make its point, back it up, and wrap it up.
> - Flag answers that speculate but don't back it up. Any good answer here should be able to draw on a wealth of available sources; failure to do so casts doubt on its validity and creates more work for anyone reading.
> - Flag answers that consist entirely of links / quotes / or references without bringing any knowledge or expertise to relate them to the question. It's awesome to draw heavily from (trusted) sources, but be sure to pull out the key relevant parts and tie them back to the specific question at hand.

I haven't seen your answers, but make sure that they meet all the points, in particular that they **address the specific question** and not just the question's theme. “General-purpose explanations” are fine when they serve as a background for a to-the-point answer, but they are not in themselves what this site is about. As [Shog9 reminded you in the very post you quote](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249/glaucoma-answer-removed-because-of-a-shotgun-approach/251#251), do not “forget to actually answer the question”.

Here's a writing tip: first, answer the question succintly. Then (before posting of course), examine what you've written.

1. Does it actually answer the specific question? If you can imagine other questions that what you've written would fit, your post doesn't answer the question, it's just explanatory background.
2. Review the question. Did you take all of the symptoms into account? An answer that doesn't account for all symptoms is probably off the mark.
3. Are there concepts in your answer that the asker may be unfamiliar with? If so, expand your explanation of these concepts. You'll often need to introduce these concepts before the part that you've already written, but make sure that they don't drown the answer. Using clearly-titled sections can help.
4. What claims are you making in this post? Provide at least one [reliable reference](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/how-can-we-prevent-users-from-cherry-picking-references) for each claim.

Comment: Thanks for the good tips, but I don't think it would help in this case. I believe my answers meet standards, have necessary references and answer the actual questions. I've tried to address the removed answers individually, but it didn't help and I keep getting the same general responses and tips which are no related specifically to my case (after I've fixed all the previous concerns). For example I've answered how ['migraine is categorised'](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/253/114) however  I've received the reason like 'you often forget to actually answer the question'. That's all.

Comment: Every response or meta concern was advising generally something that wasn't actually relevant to my case like I should answer the questions (which I clearly did and fixed every concern that was raised), however the meta responses them-self doesn't address my questions at all (which exact action I should take next or which sentences are not right or what is expected from me), so it's not fair.

Answer (score 11):

I referenced your "personal style" for two reasons:

1. this isn't an isolated problem, and I want you to reexamine how you're answering questions here; fixing individual problems with individual posts amounts to treating symptoms while ignoring the root cause.
2. by leaving open the question of *why* you're answering this way, I hoped to allow you to [save face](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_(sociological_concept)).

But, you misinterpreted that. So allow me to be blunt:

Your "style" has caused you to repeatedly fail to actually **address the question being asked.** You write badly-assembled lists of facts, out-of-context quotes and erroneous conclusions that are *at best* tangential to the questions you're answering and at worst are actively misleading by purporting to be answers while making no effort whatsoever to actually **solve the asker's stated problem.**

It's irresponsible and it has to stop. You can change how you answer questions here, or you can continue seeing them deleted.

I recommend that you carefully read and follow [Gilles' excellent advice](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/should-my-answers-get-removed-because-of-my-personal-style/256#256).

Comment: Your blunt and criticism accepted, thanks. I think this is the result of people demanding references for every half a sentence, so I wanted to be formal and compatible (paraphrased) with official sources (just to be on the safe side) and this is what you get in return. I'll try to address the questions more clearly. Your answer doesn't address my existing removal, but I'll double-check again if anything else is missing and I'll come back.